# Simplify a relay based latching circuit

Tags: relay, latching-relay, latching

I have designed a relay based circuit to control main power to load.
How do I simplify the circuit to have less relays, especially less double pole relays? If necesssary, transistor is also acceptable.

When SP3T switch is toggled to the Momemtary ON position, main power flows to load and continue to flow because of a latching circuit on the relay.
When switch is on the OFF position, latching circuit is reset.
When switch is on the AUTO position, main power is controlled by a low side switched sensor.
[image]

Comment: Can't you just buy latching relays?

Comment: are there any other options for the control switch

Comment: I like the toggle switch to easily show you the state.

Comment: Seems a bit confusing- in “Auto” position the power relay is either energized continuously (if the momentary “On” has been actuated since the last power cycle without a cancelling “Off”) or controlled by the sensor (if it has not). Is that really the function you want?

Comment: Your question is missing important information.  What is the value of Vcc?  What is the coil resistance or current for the power relay?  Depending on the answers, this might be possible with a single chip replacing three of the relays.

Comment: Vcc is 28V and coil resistant is 120ohms. It might be hard to find a chip that handles big current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution that uses a single chip to perform the logic and drive the power relay.  It uses an array of medium-power (for an IC) Darlington transistors as open-collector, high-current inverters.  Each transistor is rated for 50 V and 0.5 A.  The schematic looks like a lot of parts, but it is one chip and one SIP resistor network.

The chip is a ULN2004, a very common driver part for relays, motors, displays, etc.  It is very rugged, and does well in industrial and automotive environments.  A schematic of one section is shown in the upper left corner.

Sections U1B and U1C form the latch, which is one possible relay driver.  The other is the sensor input, which is disabled except when section U1D input is grounded.

When two or more gates drive a common pull-up element (such as a resistor or relay coil), this is called a wire-NOR circuit - if either input goes high, the output goes low.  Another way to view the same circuit is as an inverted-input AND gate - the output is high only when both inputs are low.  That is how it functions here.  The output drives the relay (through U1F) only if both the switch (position 2) and sensor inputs are low.

Your power relay draws 0.23 A.  If that is enough margin for you, there is an unused section that can drive an external power transistor.  That is shown with section G and Q1.  Either sections A/F or Q1 can drive the relay.  The chip has back-EMF suppression diodes built-in.  If you go with the Q1 option, a diode must be added.

Note:  The relay decal is a generic part in my design library, not a recommendation.

[image]

UPDATE:

For the Sensor input, work backwards through the logic levels from the relay to the inputs.  To drive the relay, pin 11 must be low, so pin 6 must be high.  That means *both* output pins 12 and 13 must be high.  Because these are open-collector outputs, either one can hold the other one low.  That means both input pins 4 and 5 must be low.  Pin 4 is low only when the switch is in the AUTO position.  In both the ON and OFF positions, R4 pulls the U1D input high.  If pin 4 is high, then pin 13 is low, and if pin 13 is low, it doesn't matter what the sensor signal does at pin 12.

The Sensor controls the relay through U1E.  U1D disables that control by holding the U1E output at GND.  When the switch is in the AUTO position, it disables this disabling.  The U1D output goes open-circuit, and now the Sensor signal can propagate through to the relay.

Remember, these are open-collector outputs.  Unlike "normal" gate outputs (totem poles), where tying two output directly together can lead to component death, these parts "high" output state is really just a transistor that is turned off; the pullup resistor (R5) provides the high state only of all outputs connected to it are off.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have tried to re-designed the circuit using transistors, and the issue I had was exactly what your pointed out - two ground signals controlling a common pull-up element. I was struggled to isolate the two ground signals. What I had before would make AUTO latches as well. So your answer is really helpful. Although I will need much higher current draw for the power relay - around 6A.

Comment: I don't understand the part "the sensor input, which is disabled except when section U1D input is grounded". Can you explain more why U1F is not controlled by sensor except when U1D input is grounded? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplified schematic.

[image]

It is presumed that the power relay 'K1' does not have auxiliary contacts.

Hence a standard relay 'K0' has been used for the control function.

Also, a standard single-pole, three-way selector switch (without a momentary position) has been used.

A momentary push button switch 'S1' has been used, instead, to latch relay 'K0' and turn on the load.

Comment: I don't see where is the latching mechanism, and what is the K0 switch?

Comment: What if I can change the power relay to those that has aux port?

Comment: With the selector switch in the 'on' position, when the momentary push button switch 'S1' is pressed, relay 'K0' is energised and stays energised till the selector switch is turned to the off position. The latching action is performed by the NO contact of relay 'K0'  across the push button switch 'S1'.

Comment: Should the power relay 'K1' have auxiliary contacts, relay 'K0' would not be required as the latching action could then be carried out by the NO contact of the power relay itself

Answer (score 0):

This arrangement should work true to the original concept. It is not an extreame improvement but it does eliminate the DPDT relay, and the other relays can be simplified.

Use two SPST relays, one SPDT relay*, and the Power relay.
If the Sensor switch is capable of driving the Power Relay directly Relay-3 could be eliminated.
*Relay-2 could alternately be a SPST NC (Normally Closed) type, (the enabled state would then open the NC contact).
.

With S1 initially in the OFF position Relay-2 is enabled and both Relay-1 and the Power Relay are disabled, (Vcc is cutoff to both.)

If S1 is switched from OFF to the AUTO position Relay-2 becomes disabled and it's NC contact connects Vcc to the coils of Relay-1 and the Power Relay. In this state the Sensor switch can control the Power Relay, (via Relay-3).
D1 prevents the Sensor switch and Relay-3 from affecting Relay 1.

When S1 is momentarily set to the (ON) position Relay-1 and The Power Relay are enabled.
When enabled Relay-1 also connects a ground to it's own coil and this latches and holds Relay-1 in the enabled state.

When the momentary action of S1 returns to the AUTO position Relay 1 remains latched and continues to energize the Power Relay.

As above S1 can then be moved to the OFF position resetting the system, (disabling Relay-1 and the Power Relay).
[image]

(Note that the relay flyback diodes are not shown.)
.